# How to make multiple snowballs respawn on random positions?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to make a snowball dodging game.

How to make multiple snowballs respawn on random positions at top?

I think I should do a while loop somewhere,
but I don't know where and how to make it work.

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 
import random

WIDTH = 20
HEIGHT = 10

player_position = 0
ice_position = [0, random.randint(0, WIDTH - 1)]

while True:
    #init world
    arr = np.zeros((HEIGHT, WIDTH)).astype(np.uint8)
    #populate player
    arr[-1, player_position] = 255
    #populate ice
    arr[ice_position[0], ice_position[1]] = 100
    #show world
    arr = cv2.resize(arr, (WIDTH * 50, HEIGHT * 50), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

    cv2.imshow("game", arr)  #show image
    k = cv2.waitKey(100) # wait for 100ms

    # make the ice fall
    ice_position[0] += 1

    if ice_position[0] != HEIGHT:
        arr[ice_position[0], ice_position[1]] = 100
    else:
        ice_position = [0, random.randint(0, WIDTH - 1)]
        
    # player action
    if k == ord("d"):            
        if player_position < WIDTH - 1:
            player_position += 1

    if k == ord("a"): 
        if player_position > 0:
            player_position -= 1       
        
    if k == ord("q"):
        exit()

    if ice_position == [HEIGHT-1, player_position]:
        exit()
```

Comment: related (same question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165489/python-snowball-dodging-game and please don't use OpenCV for games. it's for computer vision.

Answer (score -1):

You would want to build a while loop around the `#populate ice` portion of your code, you will probably also want to build in a `time.sleep()` function inside of that while loop to make sure you aren't spawning snowballs so rapidly it's impossible to play the game.

Comment: never ever mix `time.sleep` with `cv.waitKey`. sleep kills GUIs.